# How to insert a new node to a single-linked list, where we do not have a pointer pointed to its head?

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, data-structures, linked-list

Given a pointer that points to an intermediate node (non-head, non-tail) on a single-link list . How to insert a new node just before the node pointed to by the given pointer ?

Example, 
Given single-linked list:

```
  A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

Given a pointer pointed to C (ptr = &C), and a new node F, how to get

```
 A -> B -> F -> C -> D -> E
```

Attention: we do not have pointers pointed to A.

Thanks

Comment: This can not be done with a singly-linked list. You could insert a node *after* C, but not before, since you do not have a pointer to the previous node.

Comment: Well *something* must be pointing at A. Otherwise, it's just lost.

Comment: "something" may be pointing to `A` so it is not lost, yes. That does not mean that the code that is inserting `F` has access to that "something", though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to implement this by inserting a new C node to the right, and writing F in the data field of the initial C node.

Comment: You'd want to do it in the other order, obviously.  But +1.

Comment: what if we want to insert F before B ?

Comment: It shouldn't be possible, not with a pointer to C. Now for the sake of argument, or if my life depended on inserting that node, the only idea that springs to mind is that If you had a way to track all allocations that go through the `new` operator, you could loop over those and cast each memory area to a list node structure, and see if the `next` field points to your current node. If so, you've most likely found the previous node. However, I don't know enough about C++ memory allocation to tell you if this is actually possible.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, It can't be done. If you need that capability, use a doubly-linked list. Otherwise, always pass along a pointer to the head of the list.